# I want to submit the form and have it say successful submission and stay on the same page

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Here is my lockcheckoutbeta.php file for the information to be input into

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="lockproject.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Locks Out Form</title>
 <h1>Facilities Departmental Lock Checkout Entry Form </h1>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h3> *All fields must be populated </h3>
 <form action="insert.php" method="post">
 <table style="width:100%">
 <thead>
<tr>
 <th>Lock Number</th>
 <th>Equipment # or description:</th>
<th>Work Order #:</th>
<th>Date OUT::</th>
<th>Supervisor Inital OUT:</th>
<th>Comments/Tradesmen:</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="lock_number" id="locknumber" 
  required="required">
    </td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="equipment_number" id="equipmentnumber" 
 required="required">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="work_order" id="workorder" required="required">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="date" name="date_out" id="dateout" required="required">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="supervisor_out" id="supervisorout" 
required="required">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="comments_out" id="commentsout" 
required="required">
 </td>
 </tbody>
 </table>       
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
 <br><br>
  <a href="http://152.116.203.115/lockcheckin2.php" target="_blank">Lock 
  Check 
  In 
  Form</a>
  <a href="http://152.116.203.115/dataout.php" target="_blank">Lock Check Out 
   History</a>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Here is my insert.php file that I am trying to get to return a submit successful message but stay at the same URL.

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "nick", "ramon", "lockout");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$lock_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['lock_number']);
$equipment_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
$_REQUEST['equipment_number']);
$work_order = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['work_order']);
$date_out = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['date_out']);
$supervisor_out = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
$_REQUEST['supervisor_out']);
$comments_out = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['comments_out']);
$date_in = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['date_in']);
$supervisor_in = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
$_REQUEST['supervisor_in']);


 // attempt insert query execution
 $sql = "INSERT INTO form (lock_number, equipment_number, work_order, 
 date_out, 
  supervisor_out, comments_out, date_in, supervisor_in) VALUES 
   ('$lock_number','$equipment_number', '$work_order', '$date_out', 
 '$supervisor_out', '$comments_out', '$date_in', '$supervisor_in')";
 if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
 echo "Submit Successful";
sleep(1); 
header("location: index.php");
header("Location:http://152.116.203.115/lockcheckoutbeta.php");
} 
else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
 }

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I just want the message to pop up saying submit successful and then the fields to clear so that another lock example can be input into the fields. If someone could help me out that would be great! Thanks.

Comment: You need to look into Ajax.

Comment: Welcome. To ask On Topic question, please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should tidy up your HTML. You are not closing your tags (`form` tag and `input` tags) and your table does not have any rows. Your page looks very weird when I open it.

I cleaned up your html and added the javascript code. **The code uses `jQuery`.** If the form is submitted the handler will return false which prevents the form from being submitted. At the same time an (asynchron) ajax request is starting and targetting your php file. It contains the input data as `POST`/`GET` data depending on your `method` attribute of the form. The `success` and `error` callbacks are executed if the ajax finished.

**Note**: This obviously does not work here because there is no `insert.php`.

Also you have to modify your `insert.php`. Do not set a new `location`-header. This will mess up the ajax request. Just print the error or the success message without redirecting.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('form').on('submit', function(){
  var data_array = $(this).serializeArray();
  var data = {};
  var method = $(this).attr('method');
  var action = $(this).attr('action');
  
  if(typeof method != 'string'){
   method = "POST";
  }
  if(typeof action != 'string'){
   action = window.location.href;
  }
  
  for(var i = 0; i < data_array.length; i++){
   data[data_array[i]["name"]] = data_array[i]["value"];
  }
  
  console.log(data);
  
  $.ajax(action, {
   data: data,
   // dataType: "html",
   success: function(rtrn){
    alert("Data inserted!");
   },
   error: function(){
    alert("Error, could not reach server '" + action + "'!");
   }
  });
  
  return false;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3> *All fields must be populated </h3>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <td>Lock Number</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lock_number" id="locknumber" required="required" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Equipment # or description:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="equipment_number" id="equipmentnumber" required="required" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Work Order #:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="work_order" id="workorder" required="required" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date OUT::</td>
      <td>
        <input type="date" name="date_out" id="dateout" required="required" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Supervisor Inital OUT:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="supervisor_out" id="supervisorout" required="required" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Comments/Tradesmen:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="comments_out" id="commentsout" required="required" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>       
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href="http://152.116.203.115/lockcheckin2.php" target="_blank">Lock Check In Form</a>
  <a href="http://152.116.203.115/dataout.php" target="_blank">Lock Check Out History</a>
</form>
```

## Edit: What this code is (basically) doing

Your question is not a total basic question. **Your** posted **code** is the "general" way of how web pages and forms are working. You can imagine like this:

1. User is on your *Facilities Departmental Lock Checkout Entry Form* page
2. User enters the values for your inputs and clicks on `submit`
3. Client (=User) collects the data in the inputs and locates to the `input.php`
4. The `input.php` processes your input data
5. The `input.php` generates the new html output

This means that if you are using the data in the `input.php` your user has to be on the `input.php` web page! There is absolutely no way to execute a php file if the user does not open it. So your user **has** to be on the `input.php` page.

The solution I suggested is using [ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). You can think of that like a "clone" of your user. He is opening the `input.php` page in the background. You will not see the html output of the `input.php` (in your rendered DOM). So the procedure is now:

1. User is on your *Facilities Departmental Lock Checkout Entry Form* page
2. User enters the values for your inputs and clicks on `submit`

   3. ajax connection is being opened, "your clone is being created"
   4. ajax ("your clone") is accessing the `input.php` with the data of all the inputs, **your user stays on the *Facilities Departmental Lock Checkout Entry Form* page**
   5. The `input.php` processes your input data
   6. The `input.php` generates the new html output
   7. ajax (the "user clone") takse the output and sends it to your real user
3. The real user gets the `input.php` result from ajax, **he is still on the *Facilities Departmental Lock Checkout Entry Form* page**

This code is not the basic html code. If you are still learning do not use this code.

## Code suggestion

For you as a beginner I suggest another code. Modify your `input.php` so it can process the data but also shows the correct html. The following code generates the html you want. In addition it checks if the form has been submitted.

If the user clicks on the submit button the form will reload the current page. The `$_REQUEST`s are filled so the values will be saved. Then the success or error message is being printed. After this your original html will be generated again so the user sees the same page with the success message. If you want to have a different file structure have a look at [php's `require` function](http://php.net/manual/function.require-once.php).

**Note**: I changed you php code quite a bit. A lot of code fragments I used are personal taste. I like to have the insert statements in an array because in my opinion it is a very clean code. Also I fixed your new lines and tabbing style in my personal way.

Also I removed the `date_in` and `supervisor_in` because there are no input fields that define those values. You should fix that too.

The following code should work for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="lockproject.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Locks Out Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            // check if the form is being submitted
            if( isset($_REQUEST['lock_number']) && isset($_REQUEST['equipment_number']) && 
                isset($_REQUEST['work_order']) && isset($_REQUEST['date_out']) && 
                // isset($_REQUEST['date_in']) && isset($_REQUEST['supervisor_in']) &&
                isset($_REQUEST['supervisor_out']) && isset($_REQUEST['comments_out'])){
                    // opening connection
                    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "nick", "ramon", "lockout");

                    // Check connection
                    if($link === false){
                        die("ERROR: Could not connect. ".mysqli_connect_error());
                    }

                    // prepare insert statement, the indices are the column names of your table, the values are 
                    // the corresponding values to insert
                    $insert = array(
                        'lock_number' => mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['lock_number']),
                        'equipment_number' => mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['equipment_number']),
                        'work_order' => mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['work_order']),
                        'date_out' => mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['date_out']),
                        // 'date_in' => mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['date_in']),
                        // 'supervisor_in' => mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['supervisor_in']),
                        'supervisor_out' => mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['supervisor_out']),
                        'comments_out' => mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['comments_out'])
                    );

                    // add quotes
                    $insert = array_map(function($value){
                        return "'".$value."'";
                    }, $insert);

                    // prepare sql
                    $sql = 
                        "INSERT INTO `form` (".implode(", ", array_keys($insert)).") ".
                        "VALUES (".implode(", ", $insert).");";

                    // print success/error message
                    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                        echo "Submitted successfully.";
                    } 
                    else{
                        echo "ERROR: Could not execute query. ".mysqli_error($link);
                    }

                    // close connection
                    mysqli_close($link);
            }
        ?>
        <h1>Facilities Departmental Lock Checkout Entry Form </h1>
        <div>*All fields must be populated</div>
        <form method="post">
          <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
              <td>Lock Number</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="lock_number" id="locknumber" required="required" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Equipment # or description:</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="equipment_number" id="equipmentnumber" required="required" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Work Order #:</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="work_order" id="workorder" required="required" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Date OUT::</td>
              <td>
                <input type="date" name="date_out" id="dateout" required="required" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Supervisor Inital OUT:</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="supervisor_out" id="supervisorout" required="required" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Comments/Tradesmen:</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="comments_out" id="commentsout" required="required" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>       
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          <br />
          <br />
          <a href="lockcheckin2.php" target="_blank">Lock Check In Form</a>
          <a href="dataout.php" target="_blank">Lock Check Out History</a>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't really understand this at all I'm very new to coding and I am not exactly sure what you are saying here.

Comment: @NickRamon I edited my answer. I added a very basic explanation of what my originally suggested code is doing. Also I added a more basic code which will be enough for your example.

Answer (score 0):

Add the complete `insert.php` at the very beginning of `lockcheckoutbeta.php` using this:

```
<?php include('insert.php') ?>
```

Inside insert.php check if the submit button(add `name="lock_user"` in the input tag of submit) is set using:

```
if (isset($_POST['lock_user']))
```

change `<form action="lockcheckoutbeta.php" method="post">`

What I have basically done is insert the complete `insert.php` file at the beginning. This file will only run if the submit button is set. So, after the submit button is pressed you will be redirected to the same url but will display the `insert.php` file. Hopefully this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by having both HTML and PHP on the same page. It makes it easy. When we request a webpage, the browser uses GET method. As you are using POST method in your form you can add both PHP and HTML code in the same page as follows.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
   // handle the form
}
?>
<!-- now add the html -->
```

Note that your form should have empty action attribute to say the browser to submit to the same page

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <!-- form elements -->
</form>
```

[See the demo](https://developer.hyvor.com/tutorials/demo/php/forms-one-file)

Also, there are many advantages of using this technique.

1. You can keep all the code on one page.
2. You can create sticky forms which saves previously submitted data if something went wrong. [Here's the tutorial](https://developer.hyvor.com/tutorials/php/forms-sticky)
3. It automatically shows the same page, as you need.

For more, refer [this](https://developer.hyvor.com/tutorials/php/forms-intro).

Answer (score -1):

For the form you can set the **`action`** to be

```html
<form method="post" action="">

or    

<form method="post" action="lockcheckoutbeta.php">
```

Then for the PHP use **`isset`** like this:

```html
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include 'insert.php';
} else {
    echo '
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="lockproject.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Locks Out Form</title>
 <h1>Facilities Departmental Lock Checkout Entry Form </h1>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h3> *All fields must be populated </h3>
 <form action="insert.php" method="post">
 <table style="width:100%">
 <thead>
<tr>
 <th>Lock Number</th>
 <th>Equipment # or description:</th>
<th>Work Order #:</th>
<th>Date OUT::</th>
<th>Supervisor Inital OUT:</th>
<th>Comments/Tradesmen:</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="lock_number" id="locknumber" 
  required="required">
    </td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="equipment_number" id="equipmentnumber" 
 required="required">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="work_order" id="workorder" required="required">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="date" name="date_out" id="dateout" required="required">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="supervisor_out" id="supervisorout" 
required="required">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="comments_out" id="commentsout" 
required="required">
 </td>
 </tbody>
 </table>       
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
 <br><br>
  <a href="http://152.116.203.115/lockcheckin2.php" target="_blank">Lock 
  Check 
  In 
  Form</a>
  <a href="http://152.116.203.115/dataout.php" target="_blank">Lock Check Out 
   History</a>
  </body>
  </html>
    
    ';
```